# How to alter charset in MailItem's HTML body?

Tags: vba, outlook, character-encoding, mailitem

I have an Excel macro sending personalized files as Outlook email attachments.

The HTML message body is taken from an email received in Outlook.

The charset attribute in 'head' was set to 'iso-8859-1' (ISO Western Europe) and it doesn't support some characters specific to Hungarian. I changed it to 'iso-8859-2' (ISO Central Europe) but the email is still sent in iso-8859-1.

I also set the MailItem's InternetCodepage property to 28592, which does the same in theory, but still no success.

The original meta tag extracted from an email:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
```

The modified tag:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-2'>
```

The VBA to set the encoding:

```
.InternetCodepage = 28592
```

At runtime, after setting the HTMLBody property, this meta tag is missing from the string.

Result:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
```

You'd be right to assume that the Outlook settings are interfering, but I set the encoding to 'Central European (ISO)' for outgoing messages.

Comment: Why not always use UTF-8? You can also HTML encode any extended characters in the HTML body.

Comment: Good idea, but how can I achieve that? At some point in the current procedure it's getting reset to ISO Western EU :(

Comment: Your original HTML needs to have extended characters encoded, this way HTML-wide charset won't even matter.

Comment: Sounds good, Dmitry. Can you provide example HTML code?

Comment: It all depends on how exactly you generate the HTML file.